# creating optimised mysql database

Tags: mysql, database

I am very new to mysql database,

I am building a arduino based temperature and humidity sensor for my home, so far I have got success reading temperature and humidity and uploading to mysql database, now I want to create finalised table in my sql database . I assume the table should be optimized before I take a deeper dive.

So from my understanding , I am going to create a table with below query :

```
CREATE TABLE tempHumidLog
(
     id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     timeStamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     out_temperature int(11) NOT NULL,
     out_humidity int(11) NOT NULL,
     out_light_sensor int(11) NOT NULL,
     rain_sensor int(11) NOT NULL,
     drawing_room_temperature int(11) NOT NULL,
     drawing_room_humidity int(11) NOT NULL,
     bed_Room_temperature int(11) NOT NULL,
     bed_room_humidity int(11) NOT NULL,
     kitchen_temperature int(11) NOT NULL,
     kitchen_humidity int(11) NOT NULL,

)
```

the data from rain_sensor and out_light_sensor never goes below 0, and temperature  can be assumed it will never go below -50 and humidity is always positive.

based on that am going correct in making above table ? Actually I am not sure if we can change the data type of  a table at later stage after some data has already been punched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin with, let's start by adapting your question to the proper terminology. What you presented is not a **query** but a **command**. The word **query** should be used only when you are *asking a question to the database*.

Second, the contents of your table appears to be OK except for a couple of things:

1. It is not clear why do you need the ID (I can't imagine a situation in which you would be asking a question - i.e. issuing a ***query*** using this field),
2. You are not defining any indices, meaning that whenever you want to retrieve data, a full table scan will take place.

To properly complete your table definition, assess which **questions** you are going to ask in relation to this table and, based on this assessment, add some indices.

As per changing data-type of columns, you indeed might find difficulties to perform it once the table contains data. Still, this can be easily solved by executing simple commands:

1. Create a new table (with a temporary name) in which the columns will have the new (correct) data-type,
2. Copy the contents of the old table into the new using a command like:

   `INSERT INTO NewTable ([list of fields to receive the values])
       SELECT ([list of fields to be copied]) FROM OldTable ;`

   [Note: You might need to do some casting, depending on the types being changed]
3. Drop old table,
4. Rename new table to old name.

Comment: Can you give some example of defining indices ? Will there be full table scan if I specify limit by in select command ?

Comment: I'll be glad to give you examples **provided** that you tell me which type of **QUERIES** you intend to run. Having said that, I think that the obvious candidate would be `timestamp` (e.g. you would like to retrieve measurements that took place between two date-times).

Comment: exactly , i have discarded the idea of having ID.

Comment: In that case, and assuming that you are not expecting more than one record per timestamp, simply define that column as a UNIQUE INDEX. If you are using MySQL's Workbench, creating an index is very easy. If command like, check the documentation for the correct syntax. Last, if my answer helped you, I'd appreciate if you would take 2 seconds of your time to up-vote it. Thanks!!

Comment: if you want more points help me with google chart api : http://stackoverflow.com/q/41206080/3311276

Comment: Sorry, but PHP is not one of my expertise.